# Upvote or Downvotes undo on Edit after 5 minutes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, edits

I've just found a strange feature on Stack Overflow. When I am upvoting or downvoting anyone's answer, I cannot undo my upvote or downvote until the answer is edited (after the initial 5 mins).

I am aware of the fact that the feature is that we can undo the upvote or downvote only if the question or answer is edited.

But I have found that if I click on Edit button and don't change anything in the question or answer, and I try to undo my votes, then I am allowed to do so.

Steps that I followed:-

1. I upvoted the question.
2. Then after 28 minutes I opened the question again.
3. Clicked on Edit.
4. And just after that I reversed my upvote.
5. then click the cancel button. And I was allowed to do so

Is this the usual behavior or I am missing some FAQ part?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this.

Comment: Sir I have just made the same thing on Stackoverflow site. I wondered if I missed any part of the FAQ! Thats why I asked!

Comment: What I mean to say is that I've attempted to reproduce this, but still can't change my vote. I'm not sure why this works for you, though... It definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: When you click "Edit", what do you next?  Do you cancel the edit, then try to undo your vote?  Or do you try to undo your vote with the edit window open?

Comment: @psubsee2003:- I will tell the steps which I followed. I upvoted the question. Then after 28 minutes I opened the question again. Clicked on Edit. And just after that I reversed my upvote and then click the cancel button. And I was allowed to do so

Comment: Had someone else edited the post? I can't reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Are you absolutely sure the post in question isn't in your [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1501794/rahul-tripathi?tab=activity&sort=revisions). As a 10K user, you can make inline tag edits which won't open up the edit window but still count as edits

Comment: @Mat:- Sir I am very sure about this. I have just done this. Initially I thought that this is a normal behavior but I found in FAQ that it is not possible!

Comment: @psubsee2003:- Sir I am aware of all my edits which I have made but I have done this in a question in which I have upvoted. May be that I have missed anything but I am sure about my timings and steps!

Comment: I think you should post a link the the question in question so a dev can look at the details. That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.  I agree with @Mat, a link to the specific post might be useful for the devs.  Then we just wait of Oded or one of the other devs to show up and dig into the logs.

Comment: I'm retagging this as a bug so hopefully it gets seen a little quicker and because this scenerio would appear to be a bug

Comment: @Mat:- Sir this was the link to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615225/in-oop-what-are-the-different-meanings-of-interface-in-the-different-contexts-th/19615293#19615293 Trust me I am not lieing. I have initially upvoted this question and also I had received 3 upvotes for this but  later on I was able to able to retrack my upvote. I am aware that the last edit was done by me but I retracked my vote after 28 minutes of my edit

Comment: Also the upvote on my answer was retracked after 40 minutes of my initial 3 upvotes leaving with only 2 upvotes!

Comment: @RahulTripathi `I am aware that the last edit was done by me but I retracked my vote after 28 minutes of my edit`... wait, did I read that correctly?  You retracted your vote 28 minutes AFTER your edit?  
Did you upvote before that edit?

Comment: @psubsee2003:- Yes after my edit but I am not editing it I just followed the steps which I mentioned. may be I am not able to tell you exactly but I am sure that I am able to do that!

Comment: Did you refresh the browser window at any time in the process?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I'm confused.  You did edit the post, you changed a tag.  Or did you not change that tag

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes firstly I upvoted say at 12:00 pm then I left the question with my answer. After say 10 minutes I edited the question with certain more tags and left it. And then after say 28 minutes ie, 12:28 pm I just followed the steps and was able to retrack my upvote.

Comment: @Oded:- Yes I refreshed my browser but not at the time of editing!

Comment: You never submitted the edit?

Comment: @RahulTripathi oh, then that is normal.  Once the post is edited, your vote is unlocked until you vote again.  There is no time limit once your vote is unlocked.

Comment: @Oded:- Yes when I was editing to retrack my upvote I never submitted. After I retrack my upvote I just hit the Cancel button

Comment: @psubsee2003:- Didnt get that very clearly Sir. Could you please tell me why it is normal? As I thought only if we do some edit then only we can retrack!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Please correct me if I am misunderstanding you.  Here's the order as I understand it (1) You upvote the question (2) you add a tag to the question (3) after about 30 minutes you try to edit the post again but don't actually click submit for the edit (4) you undo your upvote.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Oded:- I am just trying to reproduce the scenario. So I am upvoting the same answer again. Its 13:58pm in my time and the question linked above has 2 upvotes including mine

Comment: @psubsee2003:- Yes exactly. So is this normal behavior?

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes.  Step 2 in my comment (the tag edit) unlocked your vote, not the edit you never submitted.

Comment: Yep - a tag change is an edit and will unlock the vote.

Comment: @psubsee2003:- Sorry Sir if I am getting it wrong but I have edited the tags 30 minutes before then how come without changing anything I am able to retrack my upvote. Although now I am trying to reproduce it

Comment: @Oded:- Sir I am aware of that but what if the tags were also added 28 minutes before. I have just upvoted the same answer and trying to reproduce it

Comment: @RahulTripathi: once the post is edited, you can change your vote, even 10 years after that. There's no time limit (that I am aware of).

Comment: What @Mat says is right. You voted. It got locked. Then you edited. It is no longer locked.

Comment: @Oded:- So it means i can retrack my upvote as I have just upvoted the same question at 13:58 pm at my time. But now I have not added any tags nor did any edits and it is more than 5 minutes after my upvote. So am I allowed to do so?

Comment: @RahulTripathi - once you voted, you have 5 minutes to retract. After that, the vote is locked **until** an edit has occurred (tag changes are edits too).

Comment: @Oded:- Ok got it. May be I missed something. But trust me I was able to do what I mentioned without editing any tags not even putting as **.** in the question. Anyways Thanks for your time. And Sorry if it was too obvious. Just thought to bring to your notice

Comment: No problem. We need people to tell us when they spot bugs. This didn't happen to be one, but the next one might be.

Comment: @Oded:- Sir I accept your point. But what about my answer. I didnt changed my answer 7:12 am but the initial 3 upvotes got retracked to 2 upvotes after the answer was accepted. Trust me i am not shouting for my upvote but I thought this may concern you as you are one of the developers in SO(I have read that!)

Comment: @RahulTripathi you edited your answer five times, so all votes were unlocked on each of those edits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I believe the OP is talking about the question (which they have also edited)

Comment: @Oded see his previous comment: "But what about **my answer**. I didnt changed my answer 7:12 am but the **initial 3 upvotes** got retracked to 2 upvotes after the answer was accepted"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - missed that. But I don't know the timeline there. And it is entirely possible that a vote was retracted within the 5 minutes it was cast.

Comment: Nobody is understanding my point but I believe that I missed some point. Although I am sure that this has happened!

Comment: @RahulTripathi no. I'm 100% sure nobody can or ever retracted his vote after the five minutes time without the post being edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the comments, your steps to reproduce is missing a very key bit of information.  You actually did edit the post after upvoting.

This [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203160/upvote-or-downvotes-undo-on-edit-after-5-minutes#comment646948_203160) of yours explains what you actually did

> @psubsee2003 Yes firstly I upvoted say at 12:00 pm then I left the question with my answer. After say 10 minutes I edited the question with certain more tags and left it. And then after say 28 minutes ie, 12:28 pm I just followed the steps and was able to retrack my upvote. – Rahul Tripathi 7 mins ago

The fact is you did edit the post with a tag edit 10 minutes after upvoting it.  Once you did that, your vote was unlocked and you were free to change it at any time until you voted again (there is no time limit to changing your vote once unlocked by an edit).

The type of edit doesn't matter.  As long as it generates a revision in the post's history, then the vote is unlocked.  It does not become locked again until you vote again (and then only after 5 minutes).  Once it is relocked, it can't be changed until there is another edit.